# Automatic issue assignment not working properly

Tags: sonarqube, atlassian-crowd, sonarqube6.3

We are using SonarQube 6.3.1.21392 with Crowd for External User Authentication.

I have just noticed, that the issue assignment is not working properly. The auto assignment is not working at all and when I try to assign a user manually, I can only type maximal 15 characters. If I type more, no search results are found.

How can I setup issue assignment correctly and how can I search for names longer then 15 characters?

Comment: `15` is the maximum length of search tokens for most of SonarQube's text searches. (workaround: If you have to search for longer names include a whitespace every 15 characters - example: `Someverylongnam longnames` will make you find `Someverylongnames`).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [Automatic Issue Assignment](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment), you'll find that user should have login, email or SCM accounts matching the id of the committer to correctly assign issues to user from SonarQube.